# Why was Kohei Sawaki forced to leave Ran when Conan shot her in the second movie? (The Fourteenth Target)

Tags: detective-conan

In "The Fourteenth Target" movie, Ran was being held hostage by Kohei Sawaki, Conan picked up the gun and shot Ran, then he was forced to leave Ran (The same scene also happened when Jo Murakami held Eri Kisaki hostage and Mouri shot her).

I still don't understand why he was forced to stop holding her hostage.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because a wounded person is harder to carry even as a hostage. Conan shot Ran in the leg or knee so that she wouldn't be able to walk if Sawaki forces her to. Which leaves her with a bruise, and spares her from being a hostage with a death threat.

There's also a similar flashback of Kogoro shooting Eri at the beginning of the movie, noting that Kogoro is one of the finest and most precise shooters in the story who graduated with unprecedented marks in the Police Academy. Conan also explains that scene here, that wounded hostages are harder to carry, so they're abandoned by the criminal in most cases.

Comment: Why did he lose his job as a police officer then? Wouldn't he have explained how he had to shoot Eri?

Comment: He would've explained but he didn't feel good about shooting Eri though. Also, the movie is not canon, so it's not the exact reason he quit.